# js http GET on checkbox input

Tags: javascript, html, get

I am trying to interface a web page with some of the other work I'm doing.

I would like a html with a JS script that can post a http GET request to an IP address on my network. the URL I want to GET is 192.168.1.103:3333/relay0/(on/off)

I have a raspberry pi to see any connections to this URL and run a shell command to switch some GPIO pins which in turn switches an 8 way relay.

The problem is im not able to get to the GET request. I'm not very good with JS so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

I would like it to be automatic once I hit the checkbox it will just run the JS function.

Code so far:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="on_off1" onclick="Relay1() return-false;"/>
</form>

<script type=text/javascript>
function Relay1() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (document.getElementById('on_off1').checked){
        xmlHttp.open("GET", 'http://192.168.1.103:3333/relay4/on', false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText
        }
    else {
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://192.168.1.103:3333/relay4/off' , false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

> ```
> onsubmit="return (Relay1);">
> ```

You're returning the function. You need to **call** it and return its return value.

```
onsubmit="return Relay1();">
```

**Problem 2**

> return xmlHttp.responseText

It doesn't really make sense to return a string. You usually want to return `true` or `false` depending on if you want the form to submit.

If you never want the form to submit, then just `onsubmit="Relay1(); return false;">`

**Problem 3**

> ```
>    return xmlHttp.responseText
>    window.alert("Was on, sent to /relay/on");
> ```

After you return from a function, you can't do anything else in that function. You need to make returning the **last** thing you do.

**Problem 4**

> ```
> xmlHttp.open("GET", 'http://192.168.1.103:3333/relay0/on', false );
> ```

Synchronous requests with XMLHttpRequest are deprecated. They lock up the UI and don't let anything else happen.

Avoid them. [Use a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) instead.

This would cause problems if you needed to use the response to decide if you want to submit the form or not, but as mentioned above, it looks like you always want to cancel the request.

**Potential problem 5**

> ```
> http://192.168.1.103:3333/relay0/on
> ```

You have an absolute URI which implies a cross-origin request. Make sure [the server is set up to grant your page permission to access the data using CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

> **I would like it to be automatic once I hit the checkbox it will just run the JS function.**

Then use a `change` / `click` event on the checkbox instead of a `submit` event on the form.

Comment: ok, im a little lost. to put this simply i want a http GET when i check the checkbox. i have been looking at a lot of different examples but i dont think any of them really outright apply to me. I dont need any responce from the url i just need to hit it. the pi im connecting to has a python code which registers any connection to the url and triggers a relay.

Edit: edited my code in original Question to reflect changes

Comment: sorry found a few mistakes i made, also removed the "return xmlHttp.responseText" section and its working fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding onclick function on checkbox like below,
so after change of value it will call the function specified.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="on_off" onclick="Relay1()" />
</form>

<script type=text/javascript>
function Relay1() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (document.getElementById('on_off').checked){
        xmlHttp.open("GET", 'http://192.168.1.103:3333/relay0/on', false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        window.alert("Was on, sent to /relay/on");
        return xmlHttp.responseText
    }
    else {
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://192.168.1.103:3333/relay0/off' , false             );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        window.alert("Was off, sent to /relay/off");
        }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: tried both f the above solutions and neither worked for me. do i need to put aything in the xmlHttp.send( null ); area to replace null ? and is the link  formatted corectly (should it be in ' ' ?)